# Jasmine TypeError : undefined is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, ionic-framework, jasmine

I have this function inside a controller :

```
  $scope.delt = function() {
                $scope.data = {};
                $scope.confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
                    title: '<b>Delete user</b>',
                    template: "Are you sure you want to delete this user ?<br>can't be undo."
                }).then(function(res) {
                    if (res) {
                        API.editeTheUser.delete({ id: $scope.user.id }, function(res, header) {
                            $scope.addEvent('delete-user', 'Delete the user with phone_number :' + $scope.user.phone);
                            $rootScope.popup('delete', "delete was success");
                            $ionicHistory.goBack();
                        }, function(err) {
                          $rootScope.popup("Error", err.data.error);
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log('You are not sure');
                    }
                });
            }
```

and when i just call this function in my unit test :

```
    describe('manageUserCtrl', function() {

          var controller, window, scope,
              $rootScope,
              $q, store, API, $ionicPopup, deferredLogup;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$ionicPopup_, _$rootScope_, $q, _API_, _$window_) {
              $q = $q;;
              $ionicPopup = _$ionicPopup_;
              deferredLogup = $q.defer();
              $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
              spyOn($ionicPopup, 'confirm');
              scope = $rootScope.$new();
              API = _API_;
              window = _$window_; 
     controller = $controller('manageUserCtrl', {
                  '$scope': scope,
                  'API': API,
                  '$window': window,
                  '$ionicPopup': $ionicPopup

              });

          }));
    it('expect delete', function() {
          scope.delt();
    }); 
});
```

then I got the error

> "TypeError : undefined is not a constructor(near
>   '...}).then(function(res))({...')"

.
what is the error here,I'm new with unit test?
p.s. the code works good.

Comment: @jlogan please,can you help with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Typo at the end of the describe function - you are not closing the parent level (describe function) - note that I have added comments just for description purposes.

```
describe('manageUserCtrl', function() {
    var controller, window, scope,
        $rootScope,$q, store, API, $ionicPopup, deferredLogup;
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$ionicPopup_, _$rootScope_, $q, _API_, _$window_) {
          $q = $q;;
          $ionicPopup = _$ionicPopup_;
          deferredLogup = $q.defer();
          $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
          spyOn($ionicPopup, 'confirm');
          scope = $rootScope.$new();
          API = _API_;
          window = _$window_; 
          controller = $controller('manageUserCtrl', {
              '$scope': scope,
              'API': API,
              '$window': window,
              '$ionicPopup': $ionicPopup
          }); // closes the controller
      })); //closes the beforeEachfuntion

    it('expect delete', function() {
          scope.delt();
    }); //closes the expect rule
}); //closes the parent describe function
```

Comment: @Ebrahim Ze - the final closing brackets were missing ... this is the last line of the above snippet ..  }); //closes the parent describe function

Comment: those were missing just in my snippet but the error appears in the controller code not in the test .

Comment: ok sorry - - just wondering if you are setting res anywhere - the function requires res as an argument ... }).then(function(res) {... , but I cant see it being set?